# Минимизация блоков try...catch в коде

Tags: c#, рефакторинг

Есть служба WCF с которой клиент общается посредством HTTP протокола.
Класс клиента носит название `WcfClient`.

Есть библиотека.
В ней интерфейс `ILibrary` который отдается наружу и класс `Library:ILibrary`, который оборачивает клиент подобным образом:

```
public class Library:ILibrary
{
    public LibModel GetBooks(String inventoryID)
    {
        try { 
            return new WcfClient().GetBooks(String inventoryID);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            return new LibModel() { ErrorMessage = exc.Message };
        }
    }
    public LibModel GetBooksInDiscipline(String disciplineId) 
    {
        try { 
            return new WcfClient().GetBooksInDiscipline(String disciplineId);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            return new LibModel() { ErrorMessage = exc.Message };
        }
    }
    public LibModel GetBooksInSubsidiary(String subsidiaryId, String disciplineId)
    {
        try { 
            return new WcfClient().GetBooksInSubsidiary(String subsidiaryId, String disciplineId);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            return new LibModel() { ErrorMessage = exc.Message };
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Когда клиент не может отправить запрос серверу, он выдает исключение. При это исключение выдается именно на момент вызова функции из клиента, а не на момент формирования класса клиента. Функций много, поэтому код обрастает однотипными блоками `try...catch`.

Соответственно вопрос, можно ли как-то это минимизировать и избавиться от повторений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно минимизировать с помощью AOP / Policy Injection. Например, через PostSharp это делается в виде OnExceptionAspect:

```
[Serializable]
public class ExceptionHandler : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        //TODO Exception Logging
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;

        args.ReturnValue = new LibModel() { ErrorMessage = args.Exception.Message };

        base.OnException(args);
    }
}
```

Который можно навесить как

```
[ExceptionHandler]
public LibModel GetBooksInSubsidiary(String subsidiaryId, String disciplineId)
{
}
```

но это требует пост-процессинга.

В [Unity Policy Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660915(v=pandp.20).aspx#interception_callhandlers) точно того же можно добиться без постпроцессинга - правда, резолвить экземпляр Library придется через Unity.

Судя по всему, Library у вас и так создается через какой-то IoC Container - посмотрите, скорее всего он тоже поддерживает aop/policy injection/interception в каком-то виде.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете минимизировать код прибегнув к использованию делегатов.

Comment: Можно, тут правда один момент мне не нравится. У всех функций одинаковый возвращаемый тип, но очень разные принимаемые аргументы. В таком случае придется писать почти для каждой функции свое собственный делегат.

Comment: нет, на входе просто передавайте функцию,  а внутри делегата вызывайте функцию, вот и все.